# How to make .swf movie to play only once and stop, not repeat?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made a movie in which a cube turns and should stop but because it's a .swf movie it keeps on repeating which I don't want. I want it to play only once and stop. How can I do this? If an action script is needed, please tell what's that? I have Adobe Flash professional CS5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the last frame in your flash file all you need to do is click on the frame within the timeline click on the actions panel and then type in:

```
 stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Put stop(); in the last frame in the actionscript panel.  That should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go into your code and set your loop to false for that swf file:

```
 <param name="loop" value="false" />
```

This will make it play once after you load the page.